# Ads covering bottom of layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple layout. But I can't make it work along with an AD which I want to put in the bottom. Here are 2 screenshots with and without an AD.

**Without AD**

[image]

**With AD**

[image]

As you can see the AD when it's loaded, it covers both buttons ( which are in relative layout ). How can I make it this right, so when AD is loaded, my relative layout "bumps" above the ad ? Here is my XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/example.com">



    <com.example.touch.TouchImageView android:id="@+id/mytouchview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relat"
        />




        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
             >

             <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:background="@null" android:src="@drawable/previous"  android:id="@+id/previous"/>

             <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp" android:text="2/15"
         android:id="@+id/memeNumber" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
             android:background="@null"  android:src="@drawable/next" android:id="@+id/next"/>


 </RelativeLayout>



    <com.csjy.sfwn148282.AdView
xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/myAdView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ap:animation="fade"
ap:placementType="interstitial"
ap:banner_type="inappad"
ap:test_mode="true"
ap:canShowMR="false"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"


/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:

I did like @Szymon adviced me, but the problem I'm facing now is that layout is positioned like this , until ad loads. After that, it works like it should. How to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you. Note that you should use `@+id` only once for each variable you declare (even if you declare it in some other place than the actual element). In the code below, it is declared in `android:layout_above` and only used as `@id` in the actual element declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/example.com">



    <com.example.touch.TouchImageView android:id="@+id/mytouchview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relat"
        />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/relat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/myAdView"
             >

             <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:background="@null" android:src="@drawable/previous"  android:id="@+id/previous"/>

             <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp" android:text="2/15"
                android:id="@+id/memeNumber" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


            <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
             android:background="@null"  android:src="@drawable/next" android:id="@+id/next"/>


        </RelativeLayout>



    <com.csjy.sfwn148282.AdView
        xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@id/myAdView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ap:animation="fade"
        ap:placementType="interstitial"
        ap:banner_type="inappad"
        ap:test_mode="true"
        ap:canShowMR="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It works. But I'm facing new problem now. I have edited my question, if you want to take a look.

Comment: If he has solved your original question then the answer should be accepted and a new question started. It is of no use to anyone else with the same problem if the originally question is edited to a new one. The answers would then not make any sense. It also undermines the reward system compared to the work done.

Comment: @rootpanthera As Brianjs said, please ask a separate question. I'll be happy to look at it.

Comment: Ok I've asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252586/layout-issue-during-ad-load