# Layout issue during AD load

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem setting up layout.

Before AD is loaded it looks like this:

[image]

After AD is loaded, everything goes to it's place. It looks like this ( correct )

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? Not that only looks "ugly" for the time which AD is loading, but AD may never be loaded also, and layout could stay this way (first image )forever.

Any suggestions?

I have this XML layout:

```
<com.example.touch.TouchImageView android:id="@+id/mytouchview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relat"
    />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/relat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myAdView"
         >

         <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:background="@null" android:src="@drawable/previous"  android:id="@+id/previous"/>

         <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp" android:text="2/15"
            android:id="@+id/memeNumber" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
         android:background="@null"  android:src="@drawable/next" android:id="@+id/next"/>


    </RelativeLayout>



<com.csjy.sfwn148282.AdView
    xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/myAdView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ap:animation="fade"
    ap:placementType="interstitial"
    ap:banner_type="inappad"
    ap:test_mode="true"
    ap:canShowMR="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
```

EDIT:

After @Szymon answer layout looks like this. It's okay because it's the same while loading the AD. The problem is that now, buttons are missing..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your top level Relative Layout to a linear Layout (vertical) and then use layout_weight on the three layouts. set the layout_weight for mytouchview to 1 and the other two to 0.  This will give mytouchview all the extra space and push the buttons and ad to the bottom.  When the ad takes up space it will push the button tray up appropriately, but it won't take any space if the ad never loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try that one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/example.com">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/myAdView"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.example.touch.TouchImageView android:id="@+id/mytouchview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/+relat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
         >

         <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:background="@null" android:src="@drawable/previous"  android:id="@+id/previous"/>

         <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp" android:text="2/15"
            android:id="@+id/memeNumber" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
         android:background="@null"  android:src="@drawable/next" android:id="@+id/next"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<com.csjy.sfwn148282.AdView
    xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/myAdView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ap:animation="fade"
    ap:placementType="interstitial"
    ap:banner_type="inappad"
    ap:test_mode="true"
    ap:canShowMR="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Something is wrong with that XML. Document has 2 views? Linear and AdView. Is this right? Because I'm getting XML error: "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." Also there are 2. relativeLayout closing tags, and only 1 Linear layout opening tag.

Comment: No problem. But I'm still getting xml error: "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." Probably because document has two child views. Is this even allowed? (Getting on line where "AdView" starts )

Comment: No, it's not allowed. It has the same parent as before, you posted xml without the parent so I just replied in the same way. See my edit.

Comment: It works partially. Look my edited, answer. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @dangVarmit worked for me perfectly. Thank you for your help. I will give you +1, for your effort. :)